# In Netbeans, can you do SSH connection for PHP Projects?

Tags: netbeans, ssh

Netbean is great and I use it with FTP remote connection all the time.  However, one of my client currently only have a SSH connection.  Is there anyway to connect to it and up/down files?

Comment: you want SFTP access? in that case - it's inbuilt, afaik.

Comment: i dunno, never used ftp/sftp from netbeans. offtopic: _Use version control system. And let the server update from SVN / GIT_.

Comment: Learn how to use ssh and scp from the command line. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: Here is a link that helped me a lot with this: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html#remote-sources

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Like it was mentioned, SFTP is supported in Netbeans by default.
So select "remote connection" in your project's run configuration and use your SSH connection information (host, login and pass). You don't have to provide any private key file.

Comment: Yea it turned out to be that server blocked external connection.  Netbean works fine.

Comment: I'm getting problems uploading files through netbeans with the SSH connection. Is there any way to give the firewall a wildcard to accept it?

Comment: Can you provide images from the process?

Answer (score 5):

I've had luck using sshfs (ssh file system) on ubuntu. I create created a mount folder in my home folder and run the following

```
$ sshfs domain\\user@server:/path/to/remote/folder ~/mount/local-mount-point
```

From there I start a new (or existing) project in Netbeans at that local folder `~/mount/local-mount-point`

For a nicer set up, do a key exchange between your local box and the server (ssh-copy-id) for password-less ssh connections. Then, put the above command line in your .bashrc file.

Answer (score 2):

I do the same as Richard.

In general is easier just to mount the remote filesystem and use netbeans in the mounted directory.

I just do the following :

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other root@www.khosmos.com:/var/www/html /mnt/droplet/
```